# SQL summarizing multiple queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a question on summarizing SQL queries :

```
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Crab"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Chicken"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Beancurd"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Pork"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Fish"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Premium"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Vegetable"
SELECT COUNT(fquantity) from items where fcategory="Prawn"
```

Is there a way to summarize them to a single SQL query which will return 8 rows of result with 2 columns of data (fcategory, count) ?

Comment: If you want to retrieve only 8 categories listed above, just use this query: `SELECT fcategory, count(fquantity) AS qty FROM items WHERE fcategory IN('Crab', 'Chicken', 'Beancurd', 'Pork', 'Fish', 'Premium', 'Vegetable', 'Prawn') GROUP BY fcategory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fcategory,count(fquantity) AS qty FROM items GROUP BY fcategory
```

Comment: @NicholasLim just hit like if this query helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` to group  data by category this way:

**Query**

```
Select count(fquantity),
fcategory 
from items
group by fcategory
```

Comment: 1630 - FUNCTION food.count does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: Food.count is nowhere in OP